# Como agregarle un indicador al datagridview

Tags: c#, datagrid

que tal quisiera agregar en mi campo de Peso que les muestro a continuacion 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una palabra, es decir para los valores que esten en ZERO "0" que en el gridview se visualize como NA y si tiene un valor diferente a ZERO, que conserve el valor. no se si me explico. no tengo codigo de pormedio, para presentarlo el valor es de tipo decimal.
Espero su ayuda. gracias

Comment: Cómo que no tienes código? Hace falta ver como generas la tabla al menos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin saber de como recuperas tus datos o como los almacenas en el datagridView, lo que se me ocurre es que creas un metodo que recorra todas las filas que tengas y compares el valor de tu columna Peso, si este es igual a 0 lo reemplazas a "NA".

Algo así seria:

```
public void remplazaCero()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dRow in DataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (dRow.Cells.Item(2).Value == 0)
            dRow.Cells.Item(2).Value = "NA";
    }
}
```

2 es el index de la columna que vas a comparar (empieza a contar desde 0)

Finalmente mandas llamar tu método en donde cargas tu DatagridView, deberia funcionar.